# jqgrid numeric paging

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jqgrid, frontend

I need help to modify blow code, What I need in jqgrid paging :

First view:
Page 1 of 106 (106 items) < [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 … 104 105 106 >

Second view:
Page 7 of 106 (106 items) < 1 2 3 … 6 [7] 8 9 … 104 105 106 >

Third view:
Page 101 of 106 (106 items) < 1 2 3 … 100 [101] 102 103 104 105 106 >

```
function BuildGroupedPagination(current_page, total_pages, gridId) {
var strPages = "";
var intMaxPages = 0;
var intMinPages = 0;
var intPaginI = 0;
var li;
var link;

var myPageRefresh = function (e) {
    var newPage = $(e.target).text();
    $("#" + gridId).trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: newPage }]);
    e.preventDefault();
};

//var custom_pager = $('<ul>', { 'class': 'pageMiddle' });
var custom_pager = $('<ul>', { 'id': 'custom_pager', 'class': 'clearfix' });

if (total_pages > 10) {
    if (total_pages > 3) {
        intMaxPages = 3;
    }
    else {
        intMaxPages = total_pages;
    }

    for (intPaginI = 1; intPaginI <= intMaxPages; intPaginI++) {
        link = jQuery('<a>', { href: '#', click: myPageRefresh });
        link.text(String(intPaginI));

        if (intPaginI == current_page) {
            current = 'current_page';
        }
        else {
            current = '';
        }

        li = jQuery('<li>', { id: current }).append(link);

        jQuery(custom_pager).append(li);
    }

    if (total_pages > 3) {
        if ((current_page > 1) && (current_page < total_pages)) {
            if (current_page > 5) {
                li = jQuery('<li>', { 'class': 'pageMiddle' }).append('...');
                jQuery(custom_pager).append(li);
            }

            if (current_page > 4) {
                intMinPages = current_page;
            }
            else {
                intMinPages = 5;
            }

            if (current_page < total_pages - 4) {
                intMaxPages = current_page;
            }
            else {
                intMaxPages = total_pages - 4;
            }

            for (intPaginI = intMinPages - 1 ; intPaginI <= intMaxPages + 1; intPaginI++) {
                link = jQuery('<a>', { href: '#', click: myPageRefresh });
                link.text(String(intPaginI));

                if (intPaginI == current_page) {
                    current = 'current_page';
                }
                else {
                    current = '';
                }

                li = jQuery('<li>', { id: current }).append(link);

                jQuery(custom_pager).append(li);
            }

            if (current_page < total_pages - 4) {
                li = jQuery('<li>', { 'class': 'pageMiddle' }).append('...');
                jQuery(custom_pager).append(li);
            }
        }
        else {
            li = jQuery('<li>', { 'class': 'pageMiddle' }).append('...');
            jQuery(custom_pager).append(li);
        }

        for (intPaginI = total_pages - 2; intPaginI <= total_pages; intPaginI++) {
            link = jQuery('<a>', { href: '#', click: myPageRefresh });
            link.text(String(intPaginI));

            if (intPaginI == current_page) {
                current = 'current_page';
            }
            else {
                current = '';
            }

            li = jQuery('<li>', { id: current }).append(link);

            jQuery(custom_pager).append(li);
        }
    }
}
else {
    for (intPaginI = 1; intPaginI <= total_pages; intPaginI++) {
        link = jQuery('<a>', { href: '#', click: myPageRefresh });
        link.text(String(intPaginI));

        if (intPaginI == current_page) {
            current = 'current_page';
        }
        else {
            current = '';
        }

        li = jQuery('<li>', { id: current }).append(link);

        jQuery(custom_pager).append(li);
    }
}
return custom_pager;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blow is the code for my question, Please correct it if I do any mistake in this or any shorter way for this logic code

```
if (total_pages > 10) {

    if (current_page < 7) {
        intMaxPages = 7;
    }
    else {
        intMaxPages = 3;
    }

    for (intPaginI = 1; intPaginI <= intMaxPages; intPaginI++) {
        link = jQuery('<a>', { href: '#', click: myPageRefresh });
        link.text(String(intPaginI));

        if (intPaginI == current_page) {
            current = 'current_page';
        }
        else {
            current = '';
        }

        li = jQuery('<li>', { id: current }).append(link);

        jQuery(custom_pager).append(li);
    }

    li = jQuery('<li>', { 'class': 'pageMiddle' }).append('...');
    jQuery(custom_pager).append(li);

    if (current_page > 6 && current_page < total_pages - 6) {
        for (intPaginI = current_page - 1 ; intPaginI <= current_page + 2; intPaginI++) {
            link = jQuery('<a>', { href: '#', click: myPageRefresh });
            link.text(String(intPaginI));

            if (intPaginI == current_page) {
                current = 'current_page';
            }
            else {
                current = '';
            }

            li = jQuery('<li>', { id: current }).append(link);

            jQuery(custom_pager).append(li);
        }

        li = jQuery('<li>', { 'class': 'pageMiddle' }).append('...');
        jQuery(custom_pager).append(li);
    }
    if (current_page >= total_pages - 6) {
        intMaxPages = total_pages - 6;
    }
    else {
        intMaxPages = total_pages - 2;
    }

    for (intPaginI = intMaxPages; intPaginI <= total_pages; intPaginI++) {
        link = jQuery('<a>', { href: '#', click: myPageRefresh });
        link.text(String(intPaginI))

        if (intPaginI == current_page) {
            current = 'current_page';
        }
        else {
            current = '';
        }

        li = jQuery('<li>', { id: current }).append(link);
        jQuery(custom_pager).append(li);
    }
}
```